# Cannot bind (function pointer) lvalue to (function pointer) rvalue when launching std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, c++11

I'm having an interesting issue with gcc 4.5.2. The following code

```
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>

using std::cout;
void foo(int a){
    cout<<a;
}

template <typename T>
void goo(void (*fn)(T),T c){
    fn(c);
}

int main(void)
{
    std::thread TH;
    void (*ptr)(int)=foo;
    TH= std::thread(goo<int>,ptr,1);
    TH.join();

    return 0;
}
```

.. will not compile on gcc 4.5.2 with `error: cannot bind ‘void(void (*)(int), int)’ lvalue to ‘void (&&)(void (*)(int), int)’` followed by the second error `initializing argument 1 of ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void(void (*)(int), int), _Args = {void (*&)(int), int}]’`

However, this code does compile when the `template` is removed, and it also does compile with gcc 4.7.0 (with `template` in place).

Even if this is a compiler issue, could somebody please explain what such an error means? I would be happy to find a way to do the binding (even if this is, say, automatic in gcc 4.7).

Comment: Why support GCC 4.5.2? If you're doing this sort of thing in general, won't it be likely that some other part of the program will still run afoul of its limitations?

Comment: I'm writing a CUDA/c++ code, adjustable by a preprocessor flag; not much more of c++11 is to be found anywhere in the code (`nvcc` does not support it.. yet), so I stick to 4.5.2 for compilation, and do not like to change compilers just because this interesting issue appears in the CPU case...

Comment: @PMarecki please select Johannes' answer. I'm getting downvoted a lot and there's not much I can do about it!

Comment: @Potatoswatter on "select": your answer provides a simple workaround, and people working with templated functions for threads might find it more useful. Johannes answer is deeper, so people should upvote it instead of downvoting yours for "being selected". I will change "select" if yours: "invariably converted to function pointers" is wrong (I need to test). You might also edit your answer.

Comment: @pma you do not need to test. the answer is misleading because it says that gcc does a conversion to pointer. nowhere it does in your code. it is not only the statement that the conversion happens invariably that is wrong. it is better if you select *no* answer if you dont understand enough of this to evaluate the correctnes of it rather that to select an incorrect answer. if later you understand it you can still select the correct answer.

Comment: You are right; this is exactly the way I feel - so I'm unaccepting. Potatoswatter's solution, `&goo<int>`, does introduce an explicit conversion to pointer, though, doesn't it? This allowed me to compile the code on gcc4.5, and I'm grateful to him for that.

Comment: @PMarecki `&` obtains a pointer, but "conversion" is when it happens without an operator. Really, you might as well select Johannes' answer. He knows C++ pretty much as well as anyone out there… and it takes a lot of study to understand this entire chain of events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You stumbled upon two bugs.

The first bug in GCC is that during the "perfect forwarding"-value category deduction, it thinks that `goo<int>` is an rvalue. But `goo<int>` is actually an lvalue. So instead of deducing `_Callable` to `void(void (*)(int), int)`, it should have deduced it to `void(&)(void (*)(int), int)`. Then reference collapsing would have yielded that lvalue reference as parameter type, instead of `void(&&)(void (*)(int), int)` like it incorrectly does with your GCC version.

During the actual initialization of the parameter, it also incorrectly rejects initialization of rvalue reference parameter by the function lvalue (I don't remember what the state of the working draft was when GCC4.5 was released - but possibly the draft had it ill-formed back then). For function type expressions, the Standard allows to initialize an rvalue reference to function type with an lvalue of function type.

Resolving a template id to a function lvalue is quite convoluted, so it doesn't surprise me GCC got it wrong (see http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=7505 and http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=7505 for two examples of how many rules interact for seemingly simple things).

Comment: Thanks!! (BTW: 2nd link = 1st link). What would be the way to check what the compiler does think of object(s), in `c++11` terms, before it starts conversions/deductions? I'm now using `A=std::move(&goo<int>);` ( `A`: completely incompatible type), to get somewhat more verbose error messages. Also -- is there a way to display what type of conversion were actually performed, so that we do not need to guess? [From `std::move` I infer, that gcc4.5.2/3 really had problems with it, while gcc4.6 and gcc4.7 seem to do exactly what you say they should.]

Comment: I do not understand your comment. if you want to know what precisely happens inside of gcc, you have no option but to look into its code.

Comment: Yes, but this would be "expensive" solution. Generating errors on purpose by attempting (bad) conversions gives me (some) quick answer on what the compiler thinks e.g. `&goo<int>` is. But I need to know, that the error messages reflect the status of, say, `&goo<int>` and not of it after some attempted conversions already performed. But -- as you say -- just knowing the algorithm gcc uses would be better.

Comment: you already provoked a compiler error and i explained that the error shows that no conversions to pointers occurs.

Answer (score 4):

An lvalue is an expression representing an object that can have its address taken. For example, the left-hand side of an assignment expression to a primitive type must be an lvalue: `int i; i = 3;` is OK whereas `5 = 3` is not. The difference is that `&i` is OK but `&5` is not.

`goo<int>` is an lvalue of function type, but expressions of function type are essentially useless in C and C++. They are invariably converted to function pointers, by taking the address. The resulting pointer is not an lvalue, since that would be taking the address of the address.

The bug in G++ is in when the address is implicitly taken. Apparently the conversion occurs before template deduction when you pass a non-template `goo` but after when you pass `goo<int>`. You need it to happen earlier, so the constructor doesn't attempt to receive a reference.

The unary `&` operator suffices to force the conversion:

```
TH= std::thread(&goo<int>,ptr,1);
```

http://ideone.com/mI05j

Comment: Yes, `&` sufficed, also in my original problem. Thanks for the info on how function pointers are handled!!

Comment: A C++ compiler does not convert function lvalues to pointers just out of thin air (C does, only). GCC should not do the function to pointer conversion in either case. And I don't think it does.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb huh? §4.3: "An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T.” The result is a pointer to the function." Same as C.

Comment: In C++ "the function-to-pointer standard conversion (4.3) is suppressed on the postfix expression" (5.2.2/1), but that has no semantic effect, and this is a different context.

Comment: that something *can* be converted does not mean that something *is* converted.

Comment: i recommend you to take a read on my answer. despite the questioner claiming it in the question title, there is no function pointer argument. it is a function lvalue.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb It's a standard, implicit conversion. I didn't mention that function type parameters also decay to pointers in the signature. I thought that would apply after deduction to give the argument function pointer type, not reference type. But your line of reasoning seems better, because the lvalue should inject a reference into deduction.

Comment: @Potatoswatter i do not understand what point you want to make about it being a "standard, implicit conversion". That fact doesn't mean such a conversion happens out of thin air. As a evidence-based counter-example "true" remains a bool despite of there being an implicit conversion to "int" possible. But we don't need evidence. We can prove that no conversion happens because the Standard precisely defines when the function to pointer conversion happens and when not. It certainly doesn't happen in this scenario.